# Can I add Case Comments to an Email Template?

Tags: email, case

I'd like to be able to send an email to a customer with the last comment made by an Agent.

EG:  We need more information to resolve your case.  Such as XYZ.

The purpose of this will be to send an Email to the client once, twice and then a third final time if they have not responded - Close Case.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Jin. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Its unclear to me where you're having a problem or exactly what your issue is. We want your experience here to be a positive one where you'll be able to receive the answers you need and contribute to the community if you choose to. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by including `{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}` in the email template body where you wish to add the most recent comment.

While creating the email template, you need to select the `Case Fields` in `Select Field Type` and then select `Most Recent Public Case Comment` in `Select Field` and copy the merge field `{!Case.Last_Case_Comment}` and paste it in your email template body at the desired place.

Note: If the comment made was private, this method won't work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing, think I was looking out for the wrong field type. Thank you very much! Happy Friday :)

Comment: If the solution worked for you, accept the answer so that other people with the same question gets benefit. Thanks. Happy Weekend.